# Allow calling a method m() which belongs to class A from class B

Tags: python, class

I have two classes which are different in most aspects but they share a common method. I would like to call this method(which belongs to class A) from within class B:

It would be something like this:

```
class classA():
    def m():
        pass

class classB():


classB_instance = classB()
classB_instance.m() #here I would like to call a method m() which belongs to class A
```

I know its possible to inherit this method from classA, however I don't want to use inheritance here, because classA has other methods which have nothing to do with classB.

However, I would be happy to use "a restricted inheritance". What I mean here is... I would like to inherit this method only, but leave the other methods/attributes intact.

Is that possible in Python?

Comment: Create another class C which represents "having m()" and inherit this class in both A and B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a mixin class:

```
class MixIn(object):
    def m(self):
        pass

class classA(MixIn): pass

class classB(MixIn): pass
```

Note that using mixins works fine for small projects but they do not scale well to large projects. See [Mixins considered harmful (part 1)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246341), [(part2)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246483), [(part3)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=254367), [(part4)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=254507). Those articles point out a number of issues, including:

- namespace pollution
- insufficient separation of concerns
- fragility with respect to name clashes
- complication of the MRO
- non-scalability of the design
- conceptual confusion with the isa relationship

Even if mixins work fine for small projects, it's not good to encourage their use if they don't scale well, since small projects may grow into large projects (despite the best intentions of the author :-) ).

@mgilson's answer may be better since its explicitness avoids the hard-to-trace/namespace-pollution issue. But it is still vulnerable to many of the other issues mentioned above.

So, alternatively, using [polymorphic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) might suit your needs:

```
def m(self): pass

class classA(object): pass
class classB(object): pass

a = classB()
b = classB()
m(a)
m(b)
```

As your project grows, if `m`'s behavior depends on the type of its argument, you can extend `m` without needing to change the syntax by using [generic functions](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=237764) (see also [PEP443](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/)).

Another, better approach is to use [composition instead of inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/steverowe/archive/2008/04/28/prefer-composition-over-inheritance.aspx). See the [interface wrapper solution](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=254507) for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a regular function and just put it into your classes namespace:

```
>>> def _m(self):
...     print "Hello World"
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     m = _m
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...     m = _m
... 
>>> Foo().m()
Hello World
>>> Bar().m()
Hello World
```

This might not be quite as DRY as the mixin proposed by others, but it does keep your inheritance trees completely separate.